# Android SQLite ForeignKey Column not found in Database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio, foreign-key-relationship, android-database

After the program runs Successfully and i extract `.db` file from Android Device monitor,I can find all my Tables and columns for each tables except the Column for `Foreign key`.Can anyone why this is happening? Is there something wrong with my `Query`? Here is my Code:

```
 private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "datacollector.db";

private static final String Table_Survey = "SURVEY";
private static final String Survey_KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String Survey_KEY_NAME = "Survey_Name";
private static final String KEY_Table_Name = "Table_Name";


private static final String Table_formDetails = "FormDetails";
private static final String formDetails_KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String formDetails_field_Type="Field_Type";
private static final String formDetails_label = "Label";
private static final String formDetails_Options = "Options";

public DbHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    String CREATE_SURVEY_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + Table_Survey + "("
            + Survey_KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + Survey_KEY_NAME + " VARCHAR(30),"
            + KEY_Table_Name + " VARCHAR(50)" + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_SURVEY_TABLE);


    String CREATE_FORM_DETAILS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + Table_formDetails + "("
            + formDetails_KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + formDetails_field_Type + " VARCHAR(30),"
            + formDetails_Options + " VARCHAR(30),"
            + formDetails_label + " VARCHAR(30),"
            + " FOREIGN KEY ("+Survey_KEY_ID+") REFERENCES "+Table_Survey+"("+Survey_KEY_ID+"));";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_FORM_DETAILS_TABLE);



}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its because you have not added `survey_key_id` in `CREATE_FORM_DETAILS_TABLE`

```
String CREATE_FORM_DETAILS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + Table_formDetails + "("
            + formDetails_KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + formDetails_field_Type + " VARCHAR(30),"
            + formDetails_Options + " VARCHAR(30),"
            + formDetails_label + " VARCHAR(30),"
            + Survey_KEY_ID + " INTEGER,"
            + " FOREIGN KEY ("+Survey_KEY_ID+") REFERENCES "+Table_Survey+"("+Survey_KEY_ID+"));";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_FORM_DETAILS_TABLE);
```

Comment: There is error "duplicate column name: id (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE FormDetails(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,Field_Type VARCHAR(30),Options VARCHAR(30),Label VARCHAR(30),id INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES SURVEY(id));''

Comment: + Survey_KEY_ID + " INTEGER," change name here and in FOREIGN KEY ("+Survey_KEY_ID+")

Comment: just change in declaration private static final String formDetails_KEY_ID = "id"; to private static final String formDetails_KEY_ID = "detail_id";

Answer (score 2):

you are mapping same table column to foreign key.try this now.

```
 private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
 private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "datacollector.db";
private static final String Table_Survey = "SURVEY";
private static final String Survey_KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String Survey_KEY_NAME = "Survey_Name";
private static final String KEY_Table_Name = "Table_Name";
private static final String Table_formDetails = "FormDetails";
private static final String formDetails_KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String formDetails_field_Type="Field_Type";
private static final String formDetails_label = "Label";
private static final String formDetails_Options = "Options";

public DbHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_SURVEY_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + Table_Survey + "("
            + Survey_KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + Survey_KEY_NAME + " VARCHAR(30),"
            + KEY_Table_Name + " VARCHAR(50)" + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_SURVEY_TABLE);
    String CREATE_FORM_DETAILS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + Table_formDetails + "("
            + formDetails_KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + formDetails_field_Type + " VARCHAR(30),"
            + formDetails_Options + " VARCHAR(30),"
            + formDetails_label + " VARCHAR(30),"
             + forign_Survey_KEY_ID + "INTEGER DEFAULT 0,"
            + " FOREIGN KEY ("+forign_Survey_KEY_ID+") REFERENCES "+Table_Survey+"("+Survey_KEY_ID+"));";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_FORM_DETAILS_TABLE);
}
```

Comment: forign_Survey_KEY_ID, can you explain what is this? i got error here or is this not initialized?

Comment: you need to have a column which to store the id's of super table so you have to create a column to store them.i edited the code for your error,**not initialized**.check out now